# How to test correct data validation with Mocha using Loopback?

Tags: node.js, validation, testing, mocha.js, loopback

I'm setting up tests for already existing code. I want to test the creation of a database entry for an object, specifically how the create()-Method should behave when **incorrect** parameters are given. When trying to create the object with intentionally incorrect parameters, the Loopback upsert()-Method (which is used by our create()-Method) throws an error before I can assert the behaviour.

We're using Node, Express and Loopback for the Backend and Mocha with Chai as the testing suite. We're using the Loopback option "validateUpsert:true" in the Model of the object, which supposedly leads to throwing the aforementioned error.

The basic Model looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Field",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "numberOfSpots": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
}
```

So my test case in Mocha looks like the code below. Note the comment next to numberOfSpots:

```
it('should return null upon entering false data', async() => {
  // Given
  const givenFieldData = {
    numberOfSpots: 'two' // Using text instead of a number
  }

  // When
  const newField = await Field.create(givenFieldData);

  // Then
  assert.isNull(newField);

});
```

`Field.create(givenFieldData)` basically calls this Loopback method after transforming `givenFieldData` into a `Field`-Object:

```
FieldModel.upsertWithWhere(where, Field)
    .catch(error => logger.error(error))
    .finally(return null);
```

Now I would expect that the assert runs but it is actually never executed. The finally block also does not seem to be executed. The console logs something like this:

```
ERROR (ValidationError/3844 on M): The instance `Field` is not valid. Details: `numberOfSpots` can't be blank (value: NaN).
```

Now the test fails although the behavior is correct, i.e. the object was not created. I need to find a way to check if the object was (correctly) not created and this should be reflected by a passing test. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> `Field.create(givenFieldData)` basically calls this Loopback method after transforming `givenFieldData` into a `Field`-Object:
>
> ```
> FieldModel.upsertWithWhere(where, Field)
>   .catch(error => logger.error(error))
>   .finally(return null);
> ```

The first problem is in your `Field.create` method, it's effectively discarding errors and converting them to success result.

When an error occurs, your `catch` callback prints it to the console and implicitly returns `undefined`. As a result, the outer promise is eventually returned to `undefined`.

The value returned from `finally` callback is always ignored. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally.

Personally, I would not attempt to handle errors in your `create` method and leave error handling to callers.

```js
class Field {
  create() {
    return FieldModel.upsertWithWhere(where, Field);
  }
}
```

Then in the test, you should verify that `create` returns a promise that's eventually rejected with the expected error. For example, using [should.js](http://shouldjs.github.io):

```js
it('should return null upon entering false data', async() => {
  // Given
  const givenFieldData = {
    numberOfSpots: 'two' // Using text instead of a number
  }

  Field.create(givenFieldData).should.be.rejectedWith(
    /`numberOfSpots` can't be blank/
  );
});
```

If you prefer to discard errors and return `null`, then you can implement `Field.create` as follows:

```js
class Field {
  async create() {
    try {
     return await FieldModel.upsertWithWhere(where, Field);
    } catch(err) {
      if (err.name !== 'ValidationError') {
        // re-throw non-validation errors 
        // (e.g. cannot connect to the database)
        throw err;
      }

      logger.error(error);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```